# product price as multiplier of cost price

Tags: product, price

i had put cost price of product now i want to change price of product based on some multiplication like 2.5, 3 for all products.

How can i do it via ***magento admin or some custom code*** , is that possible **to do change at one place in admin**

Comment: Not from admin, but you can use import->export utility. CSV readers generally provide that kind of multiplication.

Comment: why you does not tried with change product price at baCKEDN

Comment: where u mean edit each product

Answer (score 0):

**Your question,is not clear in mind.**

But *may be your want to increase your current product price 2.5 ,3 times*.

### Best Option:Update product price Import/Export using Csv

So in this case,*Better idea to export current products price,sku in csv sheet*  from *System>Import/Export section  then increase those by 2.5,3 ,and Import that update sheet.*

### Using code:

Get Product collection and update product by logic:

> ```
> $collection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
>
> foreach($collection as $product):
>   $CurrntPrice=$product->getPrice();
>   // Due some logic
>   $tempPrice=2.5*$CurrntPrice
>   // below code use for time format 
>   $product->setPrice($tempPrice);
>   $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'price');
> endforeach;
> ```